# Show pinned tabs in a separate row in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

I prefer to have multiple rows of tabs in my IDEs and to show pinned tabs above all other tabs, ideally. The IntelliJ Platform supports this already:

[image: Show pinned tabs in a separate row in PhpStorm]

*PhpStorm*

In Android Studio this option is missing in the preferences:

[image: Cannot show pinned tabs in a separate row in Android Studio]

*Android Studio*

I think Android Studio is not using the latest IntelliJ Platform. Is there any way to circumvent this limitation?

Answer (score 0):

Now you can enable this feature by unchecking the option `Show pinned tabs in a separate row` in `Editor Tabs` to display tabs in multiple lines on `Android Studio Chipmunk 2021.2.1 Patch 1`.

There's a difference with the old setting, the pinned tabs will be mixed with the pinned tabs, but the position of pinned ones still be in front of unpinned ones.

[image]

After unchecking it, the tabs will be displayed like this:

[image]

The pinned tabs can be displayed in multiple rows, but the unpinned tabs will follow the pinned ones instead of in a separate line.

Comment: "the pinned tabs will be mixed with the pinned tabs". Please elaborate. 